# Netlogo: Calculate average of turtles-own list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have 2 to 10 turtles remembering a route home. The coordinate of the turtles is saved every tick to the list *path*.

```
to path-tracker
  let x xcor                     ;; gets the current coordinates
  let y ycor
  facexy x y
  setxy x y
  set path lput (list x y) path       ;; adds the coordinate pair (x,y) to the end of the path
end
```

When the turtles have all reached the target the procedure stops and are set back to the place where they started. Now another procedure starts and they should not follow their own path but should follow an average path of all paths.

So how do I calculate an average list of all turtle-own lists?

Comment: Does average list mean that the resulting list has the average coordinates from each turtle?

Comment: Sorry for making it not so clear, but yes I meant it that way. E.g. if there are 5 turtles the new x and y coordinate should be every turtles x coordinate / 5 and every turtles y coordinate / 5

Comment: Logo? :D like ye olde times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple solution which creates a list of size path-length where the ?th element is list (coordinate) of the mean of all the turtle's 0th item (the xcordinate) of the ?th element (the coordinate) and mean of all the turtle's 1st item (the ycoordinate) of the ?th element (the coordinate):

```
 let path-length (length [path] of one-of turtles)
 let average n-values path-length [
   (list  (mean [(item 0 (item ? path)) ] of turtles)
          (mean [(item 1 (item ? path)) ] of turtles))]
```

If you don't like it being so condensed, you can use the following which accomplishes the same result.

```
  let average-path (list)
  foreach (n-values path-length [?])
  [
    let meanx (mean [(item 0 (item ? path)]] of turtles)
    let meany (mean [(item 1 (item ? path)]] of turtles)
    set average-path lput (list meanx meany) average-path 
  ]
```

Comment: It is a useful functional programming construct currently missing from NetLogo.  (Sorry, the comment was really just for Seth.)